# How to get value from ajax POST?

Tags: php, ajax

I trying to get value from ajax POST.

```html
<div id="chkValue"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: "someValue = value",
        });

        function checkVal() {
            $('#chkValue').load('test.php');
        }
        checkVal();
        setInterval(checkVal, 2000);
    }); 
</script>
```

test.php

```php
$someValue = $_POST['someValue'];
echo $someValue;
```

ERROR - Notice : Undefined index: someValue

Comment: change data line in ajax from `data: "someValue = value",` to `data: {someValue: value},`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` type in ajax: PlainObject or String or Array

More docs is here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

In Your code, Its a string. You should code:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "test.php",
     data: {someValue: value},
});
```

Then

```
$someValue = $_POST['someValue']; // value
```

Answer (score 1):

get data like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data:someValue:value,
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the data values in PlainObject(Key&value) Format.
Something like :

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "test.php",
 data: {key1:value1,Key2:value2...},
});
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "test.php",
 data: {key1=value1&Key2=value2...},
});
```

Now At the server end in "test.php" file you can get the data in $_POST[key1]